# combine results of k-means cluster which is in loop

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing

I've kmeans cluster, in which it has to divide data into 2 cluster. this process continue in a loop  until it reach to a condition. SO , at the end I may get 20 clusters. I do this because I don't want to assign a specific number of clusters. So it has to continue dividing into 2.

I wanted to know how to do it in Matlab? I'm using loop but the problem is after combining data I have to change cluster number. 
Is there any function to do it by itself, rather than I assign the new cluster number?

**the following example can be one of approaches. there might be other approaches. it's ok, as long as it gives the result of combination of clusters.** for example : * first loop: 1 2 2 1 2 1 1

second loop: (it'll take first cluster and cluster it into 2 sets and then it'll combine it with previous results)

[1 1 1 1] after cluster into 2 set=> [1 1 2 1]=> combine with previous loop [1 1 3 1] ( it choose 3, because we already have cluster 2)

it'll take first cluster (of the sub cluster) again:

[1 1 1] after cluster => [1 1 2] => combine with previous loop [1 1 3 4]
Here an example :
[image]

My code:

```
[IDX,C,SUMD] = SpectralClustering(G, k); % k is two
.
.
.
if Wav > w % Wav is average weight of cluster

            Gi = subgraph(G, IDX==1); % IDX is cluster number 
            Ctemp = union(Ctemp, SpectralClustering(Gi, k)); % k is 2
 else
            Ctemp = union(Ctemp, IDX);
 end

C = Ctemp;
```

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier if you posted a [mcve] instead of us just guessing what you've done.

Comment: @beaker, I added , Is it good now?

Comment: Are you asking how to cluster numbers to each of the clusters?

Comment: If you give each 'layer' of the cluster unique group names, you won't have to keep track of which integers were already used for labels in the other branches. For example, 1 : 2 for the first level, 11 : 12 for the second level of group 1, 111 : 112 for the third layer, branching of 11, etc.

Comment: @DMR, Thanks , but I don't know how many do I have. Because there's a condition to check.

Comment: @ZahraHnn, you don't need to know the final number of clusters for the labeling, as long as you derive the sub cluster labels from the parent cluster, each sub cluster label will be unique. I'll add an example below.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the cluster labels will be unique if they are derived from the parent cluster:

```
function [clusters] =  clusterExample(data, parentCluster)

% On each level, cluster data into two clusters based on value relative to
% quantiles (AKA the median, when k = 2)

% Stop clustering if the ratio of the standard deviation of the cluster
% to the mean of the cluster is  <= .1 
% This is an arbitary stopping rule for this example
k = 2;

cutOffPoint = quantile(data, (1 / k));

clusters = nan(1, length(data));
clusters(data <= cutOffPoint) = (parentCluster * 10) + 1;
clusters(data > cutOffPoint) =  (parentCluster * 10) + 2;
clusterLabels = unique(clusters);
for g = clusterLabels
   clusterIdx = clusters == g;
   clusterMean = mean(data(clusterIdx));
   clusterSD = std(data(clusterIdx));
   if (clusterSD / clusterMean) > .1
       clusters(clusterIdx) = clusterExample(data(clusterIdx), g);
   end
end
```

In use:

```
data = rand(1,100);
startCluster = 0;
clusters = clusterExample(data, startCluster);
```

The resulting clusters each have a SD within 10% of the cluster mean (arbitrary stopping rule used for this example).